# true !== true in IE11 javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt, internet-explorer-11

we are facing a pretty strange problem in our web aplication on IE11 (other IE versions work fine).
The application is based on SmartGWT ( http://www.smartclient.com/product/smartgwt.jsp ) - GWT wrapper on SmartClient javascript framework.

IE11 goes into never ending cycles.
It happens very randomly and we have no steps to reproduce it. The complexity of our application makes it impossible to post a sample of the code. 
Most often it happens when users work with the application, then they minimize the browser window and after some time they restore it and try to continue working.

The never ending cycles are caused by strange comparison results, when expression 'true === true' results in false.

The comparison code is:

```
$wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj) === true
```

The code is executed in scope of iframe containing javascript compiled by GWT.

$wnd is the main(top) window of the web application where the SmartClient javascripts are loaded.

The isc.isACanvas(..) is a method returning true or false, depending on whether the object passed as parameter is of Canvas type - Canvas is a special class from SmartClient framework not the HTML Canvas element.

```
isc.isA.Canvas = function (object) {
  return (object != null && object._isA_Canvas);
}
```

_isA_Canvas is set on object to true (boolean true not 'true' as a string) when the object is being created.

I have added some testing code to the part where the problematic comparison is used - here's a simplified version:

```
var trueCheckCount = 0;
function isCreated(id){
  var obj = $wnd.window[id];    // objects are stored in window by id

  var comparisonResult = $wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj) === true;

  if (!comparisonResult ) {
    if ($wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj) == true) {
      alert("TRUE != TRUE  (was OK: " + trueCheckCount + "x before)");
    } else {
      trueCheckCount++;
    }
  }

  return comparisonResult;
}
```

In different test runs, the alert was shown after different number of passes. E.g. on the first run it passed 358 698 times, on the second run it passed 330 125 times …

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem?
How can 'true !== true' ever happen?

Environment:

```
IE11 (Windows7/8)
SmartGWT: v9.0p_2014-03-02/LGPL Development Only (built 2014-03-02)
GWT: 2.4
```

Some additional debugging information can be seen on screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8h18b-AMFzXa3NZZ2dOX2txb1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Wait a second.. I didn't read everything but this is hilarious. Are you saying if you do true !== true in the console it says true?

Comment: You should alert the value of `$wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj)` as well, to make sure it **is** set to `true` at those moments.

Comment: See the IE11 console screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8h18b-AMFzXa3NZZ2dOX2txb1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug in IE11.

MS released the fix. It's included in December Internet Explorer Cumulative Update KB3008923.

Installing this update solved our problem.

The technical details we got were:

The bug in question is related to reclaiming of JIT functions and cross-site thunks.
A function with a cross-site thunk is getting reclaimed.
We then change the entryPoint to the InterpreterThunk, losing the cross-site thunk in the process. 
Marshalling isn't done when calling this function.
In the repro in question, we end up with a Boolean True object from a different scriptContext, which doesn't match the one in the current scriptContext when comparing with ===.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 99% in `SmartGWT`. I recommend you to report this issue to the SmartGWT team and use the latest GWT compiler of course. We dealt with SmartGWT before and from my experience I should say it was a pretty buggy library back then.

Comment: I already reported this problem to SmartGWT team, but no response till now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your debug code that could be giving you a false impression of the issue:

```
if ($wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj) == true) {
    alert("TRUE != TRUE  (was OK: " + trueCheckCount + "x before)");
} else {
```

Firstly, you're doing a double-equal comparison here, where earlier you'd done a `===` comparison. These are different, and will give different results if the variable being tested is not a boolean.

So for example, if $wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj) is outputting an integer `1` or something like that rather than `true`, then you would get exactly the problem you're describing.

Rather than doing another comparison why not get an accurate picture of the contents of the variable by using `JSON.stringify`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($wnd.isc.isA.Canvas(obj)));
```

This will show you exactly what the value is, which should then show you fairly clearly why the comparisons aren't doing what you expect.

Secondly, using an `alert()` box to show errors is not a good idea, especially in a complex application. You should always use `console.log()` for debugging rather than `alert()`, because `alert()` can cause some JS code to alter its behaviour, which can make debugging really difficult.

This is because `alert()` blocks JS execution while it's displaying, which means that any event handlers or other asyncronous code that get triggered during that time can end up running out of the expected sequence.

I don't think this is necessarily the issue for you here, given the code sample provided, but if you have any Ajax calls, `setInterval()`s or other similar async code anywhere then you really do need to avoid using `alert()` for debugging purposes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference of '===' and '==', that's not the problem. I put there the alert intentionally to stop the execution when the problem occurs. See the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8h18b-AMFzXa3NZZ2dOX2txb1k/edit?usp=sharing  There are additional information from IE11 console.